# Collection view goes Null

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview, swrevealviewcontroller

I am working an an app where i have a collection view(Parent view) and a  SWReveal'stable view. when i select a row in table view and close the the Swreveal view controller. IN parent view all the datas are available except the collection view.. Collection view Becomes Null. 
Here my code

Parent view.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyNotificationsViewController.h"

#import "NotesandReminders.h"
#import "Cell.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"

@interface TimeTableViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,MJSecondPopupDelegate,UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
 UIPopoverController *popoverController;
  //  IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionData;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionData;
```

Parent view .m

```
-(void)TestMethod
{


    NSLog(@"taggg %d ",tag);
   NSLog(@"indexxx %@",indexPathsss);
    NSLog(@"eht collection data %@",collectionData);

   // [self ChangeCells];
}


SwREvel view controller .h


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LearningSearchCell.h"
#import "TimeTableViewController.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface LearningSearchController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@property(strong,nonatomic)TimeTableViewController *TimeObj;

@property(nonatomic,assign)AppDelegate *AppObj;

@end
```

SwReveal view controller.M

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    _TimeObj=[TimeTableViewController alloc];


    [_TimeObj TestMethod];

//from here i call the Test method of parent view controller... i am getting all values except the collection view becomes null

}
```

I even tried creating properties and sysnthesized it.. it still null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not adding the viewWillDissapear within the @implementation of this UIViewController. This makes that you're initializing the code without the object.